# Conditional Probability involving two decks of cards and coin tosses

Tags: probability

Our probability teacher left us the following exercise. I just don't know how to set up exercise. Can you help me, please?

A friend has two decks of cards in front of him. He draws one card from the first deck, of which (for questions 1) and 2)) you are able to see only the color.

Then he tosses a coin: if it turns head he inserts the card just drawn into the second deck, otherwise he does not touch the second deck at all. However, you are not allowed to see this procedure. Afterwards, he proceeds to draw one card from the second deck.

1. What is the probability that the second card has the same color as the first one?
2. Once this event occurs, what is the probability that the coin turned head?
3. What is the probability that the second card drawn is exactly the same as the first one?
4. Once the event in 3) occurs, what is the probability that the coin turned head?

Comment: Between this and your other recent questions, it appears that you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the events:

- $A:=$ "picking a card of the same color as the first"
- $B:=$ "the result of flipping the coin is heads".

In question (1), we're looking for $\mathbf P\{A\}$. Let's assume the card picked from the first deck is **black** (assuming the colors are the usual red and black), the other case is symmetrical.

- We know that $\mathbf P \{B\} = \dfrac{1}{2}$
- We know that, if $B$ does not happen, the second deck is full, hence:
  $$ \mathbf P\{ A | \overline B \} = \dfrac 1 2 $$
- If $B$ does happen, we have inserted another black card into the second deck: There are now 26 red cards and 27 black ones.
  $$ \mathbf P\{ A | B \} = \dfrac{27}{53} $$

You can now use the law of total probability to solve the problem, I'll leave that step to you.

**These are the main steps you have to do, in general**, to solve these kinds of questions: figure out what you need, figure out a few conditional probabilities, and finally use Bayes and the law of total probability.

I'll also give you a few hints about the other questions:

- In question (2), you need to determine the probability $\mathbf \{B | A\}$, which you can easily compute using Bayes' formula.
- Question (3) is pretty much the same as question 1: If the second deck is untouched the probability of picking the same card as the one you picked from the first deck is $1/52$, while it is $2/53$ in case you inserted the card into the second deck (that is, assuming that by "exactly the same card" you're simply referring to a "card-wise isomorphism", and not to "the same object". )
- Question (4) is also similar to question 2, and I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. However, I have some doubts. How do you choose colours? It seems that the first deck is constituted by red cards only, the second by black ones. But why? It is not specified in the problem.

Comment: I mentioned that the case in which you pick a red card from the first deck is symmetric to the one I described. The first deck contains both red and black cards, but since there's the same number of black and red cards, you're just as likely to get a red or a black card. It doesn't matter what you pick, it only matters that whatever color you pick, if the result of flipping the coin is heads, the number of cards of that color will increase by one in the other deck. As you can see the color is actually irrelevant.

Comment: I'm doing the computations following your answer. Well, when using the law of total probability, I have to add $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{27}{53}$. Moreover, I have to multiply by two because there are two possible colours. But in this way I get a number as 2,018....

Comment: @TheWanderer I think you misinterpreted the law of total probability here. It states that, for any system of alternatives $\{B_i\}$, $\mathbf{P}(A) = \sum_n \mathbf{P}(A | B_n)\mathbf{P}(B_n)$. I think you forgot to multiply by the probability of the alternative (in this case, $1/2$), and you should not multiply by two. If you have any further doubts I'll be happy to help.

Comment: But you fixed a colour when you say that the sentence "the other case is symmetrical". And you have two choices for the colour. Thus you have to multiply by 2. Where is the error in my argument?

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm sorry, I did not explain that step properly. Think of the two cases as conditional probabilities. Choosing one of the two colors is a system of alternatives, hence you have two possibilities, each of which may happen with a probability of 1/2. By applying the law of total probability, you get that yes, you should add the two probabilities (which you were trying to do by multiplying by two) but they should each be multiplied by the probabilities of the two cases, and we know the two probabilities are 1/2. Hence you're doing 2 * (1/2) P(...), so your 2 is simplified.

Comment: So I get $p(A)=2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot [\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{27}{53}]$?